# Как изменить длину вектора?

Tags: математика, вектор, линейная-алгебра

Если у меня есть произвольный вектор `[x y]`, то как мне изменить его длину, на произвольную длину `r`, не поменяв направление? Мне нужно не просто умножить вектор на скаляр, а умножить его на такой скаляр, чтоб его длина стала ровна `r`. Или как-то ещё это сделать, например, узнать его угол наклона и найти вектор с таким же углом наклона и длиной `r`.

Comment: Умножив вектор на `λ > 0`, Вы получите коллинеарный (сонаправленный) вектор. Рассчитать `λ` можно, поделив необходимую длину на текущую длину, которая вычисляется по формуле `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` (корень квадратный из суммы квадратов его координат). _P. S.: пояснение к ответу_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c = r / sqrt (x * x + y * y)
[ c * x, c * y ]
```